# JBoss on Linux using SQL Server Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, linux, jboss

Is it possible to create MS SQL Server connections in the standalone.xml file that use integrated (Windows) authentication to connect to the server from JBoss when running on Linux?

I have managed to do it with JBoss running on a Windows machine, but it requires the sqljdbc_auth.dll to be in the system path. That won't work on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it can be done using the JTDS driver with query string:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SQLSERVER:1433/DBNAME;useNTLMv2=true;domain=DOMAIN;user=USER;password=PASSWORD;
```